# How to file copy from a column of files in a data table in R

Tags: r, file, datatable, copy

I am trying to create a new folder with all the files I need. I have a datatable called newlist with a column called fullpath which has the file path for each file.

I have tried the code below but the error message says `"'from' path too long"` so I don't think it recognises the values as separate file paths.

```
file.copy(from=newlist[,"fullpath"], to=destination, overwrite=TRUE, recursive=TRUE)
```

I think I need to specify the files to copy first using the `list.files()` function but I am unsure how to do this with a column of files in a datatable.

Comment: Can you post what the `from` and `to` paths are?

Comment: My list which files I need are in a data table but the acutal files are in my hardrive:
    'from <- "F:/"'
    'to <- "F:/Data files"'. Sorry forgive the formatting I cant work out how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
lapply(newlist[,"fullpath"], function(x) file.copy(from=x, to=destination, overwrite=TRUE, recursive=TRUE))
```

Edit:

If your paths do not contain extensions, you can use this code instead:

```
lapply(newlist[,"fullpath"], function(x) {
  # Find the file in the given directory with the basename and add a wildcard extension
  f <- file.path(dirname(x), list.files(dirname(x), paste0(basename(x), ".*")))
  file.copy(from=f, to=destination, overwrite=TRUE, recursive=TRUE)
})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have tried that and got False 1000 times. Where the files are located is "F:/" and the column "fullpath" in newlist is the list of the files I need. So maybe I need to change the from to incorporate "F:/"?

Comment: can you share an example of what the path is inside `newlist[,"fullpath"]`, and what is the actual file location of the file?

Comment: I am working from my hardrive which is `F:/` within that are 5 folders. I am working with camera trap data so each folder is a different area and each subfolder is a different camera so the paths in the datatable follow this formula "F:/area/camera/picture" e.g. `F:/registros RPPNPC/OCCAJ01/PICT0005`  Maybe I need to specify `from="F:/"` but then I don't understand how to use the list of files in the datatable to select which files to copy. Sorry I am very new to R and struggling somewhat.

Comment: Is the path in your table missing extensions? Can you try to run `file.exists(newlist[1,"fullpath"])`

Comment: Oh yes it says it doesn't exist. Must be because I am missing the extensions. Thanks for pointing that out. After looking at some of the data I have been given they all have different extensions e.g. .AVI or .ASF so I will try work out how to add them and then hopefully it will work. Thank you.

Comment: @KateS-G I have modified the code to work even if your paths don't contain the extensions. So long as there aren't files with the same name but different extensions. More modifications will have to be done if thats the case. Do mark the question as solved if this helps you! cheers

Comment: Thank you! The issue I am having now is that the database I was given doesn't have the file names exactly the same. For example some of the pictures are called a(1) but are in the database as a1. Also I need to know the subfolders that they were in as this is the location they were taken. I think I am just going to have to do it manually but thank you so much for all your help!